# How do I fix this error- Element 'reference': This element is not expected on product detail page

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.4

I am using Magento 2.3.4. Some product detail page get below error, Please help Thanks in Advance

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'reference': This element is not expected.
Line: 1


Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'reference': This element is not expected.
Line: 1

<pre>#1 Magento\Framework\Config\Dom->__construct() called at [lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:121]
#2 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject() called at [lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php:108]
#3 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create() called at [lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:56]
#4 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create() called at [lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Config/DomFactory.php:43]
#5 Magento\Framework\Config\DomFactory->createDom() called at [lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Model/Layout/Update/Validator.php:141]
#6 Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Update\Validator->isValid() called at [lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Model/Layout/Merge.php:512]
#7 Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Merge->_validateMergedLayout() called at [lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Model/Layout/Merge.php:488]
#8 Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Merge->load() called at [lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Builder.php:86]
#9 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->loadLayoutUpdates() called at [lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Builder.php:63]
#10 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->build() called at [lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout.php:257]
#11 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->build() called at [lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout.php:882]
#12 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->getBlock() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:414]
#13 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->getBlock() called at [app/code/Magento/Cms/Helper/Page.php:215]
#14 Magento\Cms\Helper\Page->prepareResultPage() called at [app/code/Magento/Cms/Controller/Noroute/Index.php:47]
#15 Magento\Cms\Controller\Noroute\Index->execute() called at [lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Action/Action.php:108]
#16 Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch() called at [lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#17 Magento\Cms\Controller\Noroute\Index\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#18 Magento\Cms\Controller\Noroute\Index\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#19 Magento\Cms\Controller\Noroute\Index\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated/code/Magento/Cms/Controller/Noroute/Index/Interceptor.php:26]
#20 Magento\Cms\Controller\Noroute\Index\Interceptor->dispatch() called at [lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController.php:159]
#21 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->processRequest() called at [lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController.php:98]
#22 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch() called at [lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#23 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#24 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [app/code/Magento/Store/App/FrontController/Plugin/RequestPreprocessor.php:99]
#25 Magento\Store\App\FrontController\Plugin\RequestPreprocessor->aroundDispatch() called at [lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]
#26 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [app/code/Magento/PageCache/Model/App/FrontController/BuiltinPlugin.php:73]
#27 Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch() called at [lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]
#28 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#29 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php:26]
#30 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch() called at [lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Http.php:116]
#31 Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php:24]
#32 Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch() called at [lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Bootstrap.php:261]
#33 Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run() called at [pub/index.php:40]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

THis means you have in one of your layout xml files or in the "Layout Update XML" field for some of your products something like this

```
<reference .....
```

This tag is not allowed in the layout files. most probably should be

```
<referenceBlock ....
```

or

```
<referenceContainer ....
```

Look in your xml files for the text `<reference` (with a space at the end to avoid false positives) and remove or fix the occurrences.
If it's not in the xmls look in the table `catalog_product_entity_text` .

Comment: Thanks @Marius for quick respond

Answer (score 1):

**First, checkout the link** https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/layout-types.html

`<reference></reference>`  is a layout tag used at **Magento 1**. **This tag does not support for Magento 2**.

**In somewhere at your code or database, this tag is exited,. you need to remove those codes/database**.

I guess that in your case the issue at your database, some products has those layout.

As mention **@marius** https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/312436/4564 you need to go to `Layout Update XML` tab your code product at admin and removed those code.

It will resolve your issue.

Comment: Thanks @amit_bera for quick respond

Comment: could you please check this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/313448/magento-2-2-6-disk-space-utilization-very-fast