# Magento 2.2.6 disk space utilization - /var/lib/mysql/ folder is taking 43 gb

Tags: magento2, database, magento2.2.6, full-page-cache

Due to some reason my magento 2 website  **(Magento ver. 2.2.6)** taking too much space from the server . Yesterday there is 1.2 gb available now only 240mb available . Please help on this .

Please see the attached picture now

[image]

> UPDATE : **I have found that most of the disk space is taken by
>   /var/lib/mysql/webna** this folder **(42 gb)**.  Here webna is my database name .In that folder i can see **lots of IBD , FRM, MYI** files. There is on file inside the webna folder called **mageplaza_smtp_log.ibd and it's file size is 43 gb**.

Please see the below image 
[image]

Comment: What is your total available space?

Comment: i have total 50gb available. Yesterday when i have space issue i removed 1.2 gb from server now after 12 hour 1.2gb disk space also used 0% left .

Comment: Check size of var/session ?

Comment: i have checked the var/session folder but it is only 100 mb

Comment: total size of /var/log/httpd is 676 mb

Comment: i have update the question . Please  check

Comment: Did you tried to check what is saved into logs? maybe there is problem with smtp connection / sending email ? Just investigate Your logs files from magento and apache

Answer (score 1, accepted):

var/cache - store all cacheable objects but not page cache

var/page_cache cache from full page cache (if you don't use varnish or redis)

Doc:
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/howdoi/php/php_clear-dirs.html

Your issue can be related with advanced reporting, but I don't know what version of Magento you use.

Check /tmp/analytics is it  taking a lot of space?

Issue Magento 2.2.6 -advanced reporting

https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Version-Upgrades/Disk-space-issues-related-to-Advanced-Reporting-cron-after/td-p/107219

You can install ncdu on server , it's nice visualization to find what is taking a lot of space.

Command:

```
ncdu /
```

Update:
Mageplaza SMTP log file was large.

Comment: dear friend my magento version is Magento ver. 2.2.6 . Now how can  i solve this issue ?

Comment: I checked solution in the link . I don't have lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Archive/Tar.php  (Because there is no folder named Magento in internal folder) . But i have vendor/magento/framework/Archive/Tar.php . But the tar.php is last modified in 09/06/2018 . I think i am using magento 2.2.6 for last one year but the issue is just happens in the last 3, days

Comment: I have removed 2 repetition of array_shift($dirFiles); in Tar.php and put $dirFiles = array_diff($dirFiles, ['..', '.']); as per the solution .I need to run any command in cmd after the code changes . Now how can i free up some space from server ? How can i make sure this is not happen again

Comment: after the change in tar.php file also i free up 40 mb by deleting some unnecessary files i uploaded previously but after 10 minutes now i have only 25 mb left . Please help

Comment: I don't have analytic folder in /var/www/html/var/tmp . And Both  /var/tmp folder & /var/www/html/var/tmp  is empty

Comment: total size of /var/log/httpd is 676 mb

Comment: Please check /tmp/ analytics not in Magento dir

Comment: /tmp folder have onlu 2 mb . Actualy whre it is located ? there is a temp folder outside magento installation and it size is 2mb . But there is no analytic folder inside tmp folder

Comment: So it's not your issue. Just install ncdu and check what is taking your disk.

Comment: could you please tell how can i install ncdu . We have aws server

Comment: I have found that most of the disk space is taken by /var/lib/mysql/webna this folder

Comment: You can change in Magento backend => mageplaza SMTP configuration. To limit logs or disable them.

Comment: thank you friend . I will check that now. But can i delete the ibd fie ?

Comment: i have disable the  mageplaza SMTP from the backend .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108437/discussion-between-abilash-er-and-bartzalas).

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you're using Mageplaza SMTP module.

This module has a configuration setting to delete all emails after X days. Simply set to 30 days, and the next cron run will reduce your database size.

Comment: could you please check this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/315691/magento-2-disable-delete-product-action-from-some-admin-user

Answer (score 0):

> Did you check auto Backup (Scheduled Backup ) is enabled, under
>   store->Configuration->ADVANCED->System->Backup Settings. you have to
>   maintain your Backup Scheduled.

*What specific version of Magento are you on?*

How many SKU do you have in your store? #Sku's will drive page cache and block cache growth.

Its possible images being resized are also probably increasing storage space - when you import product photos we don't re-size the images until the store takes traffic. Your store is getting traffic and triggering the image resizes. You'll have a # of image resizes based on the # of different images your theme uses.

Have you tried flushing your cache? That should clean up the cache files from var/. You'd want to do that after you upgraded anyway so there's no harm in doing it before to reduce your backup time.

> reference https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/9458#issuecomment-298407480